# Wrapper class as method return type

Tags: java

Can someone please explain how/why is this allowed in Java?

```
public class Test {
private int text;

public Integer getText() {
    return text;
}
```

I am basically having the wrapper class as the return type, while I am infact returning a primitive.

Comment: google for autoboxing

Comment: Java automatically takes care of autoboxing

Answer (score 4):

Because Java supports [Autoboxing and Unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in versions 5 and up. That is an example of the former, but the later is equally important (and the reverse conversion). Per the link,

> *Autoboxing* is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code: (From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
    li.add(i);
```

Although you add the int values as primitive types, rather than Integer objects, to `li`, the code compiles. Because `li` is a list of Integer objects, not a list of int values, you may wonder why the Java compiler does not issue a compile-time error. The compiler does not generate an error because it creates an Integer object from i and adds the object to `li`. Thus, the compiler converts the previous code to the following at runtime:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 50; i += 2)
    li.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

Converting a primitive value (an int, for example) into an object of the corresponding wrapper class (Integer) is called autoboxing. The Java compiler applies autoboxing when a primitive value is:

- Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the corresponding wrapper class.
- Assigned to a variable of the corresponding wrapper class.

Answer (score 1):

From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) : Since java 5 **Autoboxing is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes. For example, converting an int to an Integer, a double to a Double, and so on.**

The java compiler applies autoboxing usually when -

- Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the
  corresponding wrapper class.
- Assigned to a variable of the corresponding wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sake of performance, not everything in Java is an object.** There are also primitives, such as int, long, float, double, etc.

**For example** java.lang.Integer class :-

1. It wraps an int.
2. Has two static final fields of type int: MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE.
3. MIN_VALUE contains the minimum possible value for an int (-2^31) and MAX_VALUE the maximum possible value for an int (2^31 - 1).
4. It also has two constructors - public Integer (int value) & public Integer (String value).
5. **Integer has the no-arg byteValue, doubleValue, floatValue, intValue, longValue, and shortValue methods that convert the wrapped value to a byte, double, float, int, long, and short, respectively.**
6. **In addition, the toString method converts the value to a String.**
7. **Static methods parse a String to an int (parseInt) and convert an int to a String (toString).**

`class AutoBox {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // autobox an int
        Integer a = 100; 
        // auto-unbox
        int b = a; 
        System.out.println(b + " " + a);    // displays 100 100
    }
}`

Answer (score -2):

This feature has been added in Java 5.

**text** gets converted automatically into Integer by compiler. So basically its a syntactic sugar that can shorten your code (otherwise you would do conversions back and forth by yourself). Of course it has its price and if this happens a lot (I mean really a lot, big loops, frequent invocations and so forth), it can become a performance issue, so when using it, just remember the it happens under the hood and you'll be fine.

```
Integer.valueOf(text)
```

is called under the hood

The feature is called autoboxing btw

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  The `Integer` is not necessarily created with `new Integer(text)` - there's a cache of pre-boxed `Integer`s.

Comment: I think you're wrong. Autoboxing also happens for doubles, for example. maintaining the cache internally is too expensive. Even for all integers you can't keep all the integers in cache

Comment: Its true, btw that some integers are kept in cache (look at Integer$IntegerCache class. In fact values range from -128 to 127 are kept in this cache, but its not true for all the integers and IMO certainly not related to Autoboxing

Comment: Now that you've fixed your answer, I have removed my downvote. Perhaps the other downvoters could do likewise.  The autoboxing process does indeed give you an `Integer` from the cache if the value is between -128 and 127; and makes a new `Integer` if the value is outside this range.